# oc command not found in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins pipeline,[image] but the "OpenShift commands" commands are not being recognized.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that the `oc` commands work fine when you use a terminal to run them on the host machine, but they don't work with the Jenkins pipeline? I've had this happen to me when I install Maven and other tools, where Jenkins doesn't recognize the command until I restart Jenkins (or the whole host machine).

Secondly, is Jenkins running with a separate Jenkins user? If so, make sure that the user has access to `oc` as well.

Finally, if nothing works, try adding this line before you use `oc`

```
PATH=$PATH:~/path/to/oc
```

This directly adds the `oc` command to the path before your code runs. This way, you can make sure that there isn't something wierd going on with the `oc` command.

Comment: I have tried to add in the jenkins pipeline syntax but it keeps saying about bracket. please see the screenshots

Comment: The command is an `sh` command and should go inside a regular sh script: `sh 'PATH=$PATH:~/path/to/oc'`. Also, the `path/to/oc` should point at the actual path where `oc` is found.

Comment: Do you mean i need to download oc client in the openshift jenkins pods?

Comment: How are you using openshift? With the openshift plugin?

Comment: i am seeing this issue Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "oc" (in directory "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/mizuno-jenkinsfile2"): error=2, No such file or directory